# work with result of pyspark.sql.SQLContext in pyspark

Tags: python, sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

[image]

I am working with pyspark.sql.SQLContext and have a dataframe as shown above. I have:

```
message_df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT message FROM challenge0_df WHERE (value > (AVG(value) + (4 * stddev(value)))) OR (value < (AVG(value) - (4 * stddev(value))))")
```

when running the code

```
display(message_df)
```

I get the error:

```
SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 43.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 43.0 (TID 58, localhost): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: (avg(cast(input[2, StringType] as double)),mode=Complete,isDistinct=false)
```

Any idea on how can I see the message_df in pyspark?

Comment: what was the error ? how does your dataframe look like ?

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DataFrame' and 'int'

Comment: can you please show sample of your dataframe ?

Comment: you are trying to add Dataframe object and 1 . that is the error

Comment: I see, how can I fix this error then?

Comment: try `average_value.collect()`, it will return a list, with a single `Row`

Comment: I added a picture of dataframe to the main question, please let me know if I can use .rdd method to convert a dataframe to rdd?

Comment: why do you want to convert it to an RDD ? `Dataframes` are also distributed in nature

Comment: @frank Actually the general picture is like this:
I need to find all the values greater or less than 4 standard deviation from mean. then I need to find the corresponding message column. In this context what is the roadmap that you suggest?
\\

Another question is that if I use `average_value.collect()` then how can I add two Row objects or multiply a Row object by a number?

Thanks